# NoneType has no attribute (import confusion)

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-import

I set a database instance shared by many models:

Database.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from models.shared import load_db

def init_db(app):
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    load_db(db)
    from models.user import User
    from models.another_model import AnotherModel
    from ...
```

`init_db` is called from `create_app` in my main `server.py` file.

Shared.py:

```
db = None
def load_db(_db):
    db = _db
    print(db)
```

User.py:

```
from .shared import db
print("User model defined.")
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    hash = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

When `init_db` is called from the `create_app` method in my main file I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

Why am I getting this error? When importing the model modules from inside `init_db` shouldn't their code run after I call `load_db`? Looking at the order of the print statements `db` is clearly set before any model uses it:

```
<SQLAlchemy engine=mysql://root:***@localhost/db_name?charset=utf8>
User model defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
def load_db(_db):
    db = _db
    print(db)
```

You're actually declaring a variable `db` local to the function `load_db`.
To actually refer to global `db` variable try `global db` expression:

```
def load_db(_db):
    global db
    db = _db
    print(db)
```

I find this code pretty flaky, though, I would think about using singletones or some other approach.

Consider a case where you imported `db` **before** it has been initialized. Like:

```
from .shared import db
save_for_later_use(db)
```

Even if you replace the `db` in `shared` module, `shared.db` will point to the initialized value, while you'll have uninitialized value already pointed to by variable  you stored somewhere in `save_for_later_use`.
In other words, you've replated what `shared.db` points to, but whichever code tried to remember `shared.db` before the initialization will still hold a pointer to `None`.